# how to colorize syntax using R + Sweave?

Tags: beamer, listings, sweave

I'm writing a LaTeX document using Sweave (a Beamer presentation, really), which weaves R code and LaTeX. Is there a way to make my chunks of code and its output highlighted? I could use listings package but that would mean I would have to rummage through the .tex file and wrap all `Schunks` so I'm looking for perhaps more elegant solutions if currently available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`SweaveListingUtils`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SweaveListingUtils/index.html) package contains additions to Sweave  that enables pretty-printing input and output using the LaTeX [`listings`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=listings) package.  Example usage can be found in the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SweaveListingUtils/vignettes/ExampleSweaveListingUtils.pdf).

Another alternative is to override the `Schunk`, `Sinput` and `Soutput` environments using `\renewenvironment` so that they do whatever you want them to.

Comment: "Continued" at Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808052/sweave-syntax-highlighting-in-output